# How to create mirror of mysql database for switching purpose in case of emergency?

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I have around 400 GB Live mysql Databases on one server and I like to create a mirror for this database.
In the server I have database ranging from 1 GB to 100 GB.
What are the best practices available that I can use?
My purpose is that I should be able to switch in case of emergency.
It should have all live data.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be better on serverfault.com (even though I accidentally selected uservoice :()

Comment: if Greg's answer solved your problem you should mark it accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the emergency...

For live data, [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) is the way to go, but an accidental `DROP` will be replicated straight across...

Also, are you looking to survive a building disaster, or just a server/drive/hardware crash?

Comment: DROP is not a problem if you make full daily backups and store replication logs since backup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
 I am looking to survive both. Once I can have copy, then I can move the replicated server to a new location and possibly use rsync to get up to date for building disaster.

Comment: You need 2 forms of security: redundancy (RAID, replicated server) and backups.  They'll protect you from two different types of emergency.